# Open CV python error when drawing rectangle over reference image

Tags: python, opencv

I'm following this tutorial on YouTube on how to use object detection.

I am able to detect the object in the image with an accuracy of 100% percent, but when I try to draw a rectangle it gives me an error message:

```
in <module>
    cv.rectangle(haystack_img, top_left, tuple(bottom_right),
cv2.error: OpenCV(4.7.0) :-1: error: (-5:Bad argument) in function 'rectangle'
> Overload resolution failed:
>  - Can't parse 'pt2'. Expected sequence length 2, got 3
>  - Can't parse 'pt2'. Expected sequence length 2, got 3
>  - argument for rectangle() given by name ('color') and position (3)
>  - argument for rectangle() given by name ('color') and position (3)
```

Here's my code:

```
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np


haystack_img = cv.imread('IBL_FULLSIZE.png', cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
needle_img = cv.imread('CAT_B.png', cv.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

result = cv.matchTemplate(haystack_img, needle_img, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
cv.imshow('asdfsdf', result)
cv.waitKey()


# cv.imshow('Result', result)
# cv.waitKey()
# cv.destroyAllWindows()

# Get the best match position
min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv.minMaxLoc(result)

print('best match top left position: %s' % str(max_loc))
print('Best match confidence: %s' % max_val)

print(str(max_loc))
cv.waitKey()

# Setting a threshold
threshold = 0.9
if max_val >= threshold:
    print('FOUND ONE')

    # get dimensions of the needle image
    needle_w = needle_img.shape[1]
    needle_h = needle_img.shape[0]

    top_left = max_loc
    bottom_right = (top_left[0], needle_w, top_left[1] + needle_h)

    cv.rectangle(haystack_img, top_left, bottom_right,
                 color=(255, 0, 255), thickness=2)

    cv.imshow('boxResult', haystack_img)
    cv.waitKey()

else:
    print('error')
```

Tried changing things around in the cv.rectangle settings.
Tried different matching templates

Comment: Try replacing `bottom_right = (top_left[0], needle_w, top_left[1] + needle_h)` with `bottom_right = (top_left[0] + needle_w, top_left[1] + needle_h)`.

Comment: Wow I defintely overlooked that one! Thank you very much. It worked!